# Why doesnt my background image show for iOS7 devices?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am trying to display the default image as the background of a iOS7 simulator, but its just white.  It works on simulators that are older.

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = image;
```

Comment: Are you using Asset Catogory? Can you get the image correctly? Maybe try to see is `[UIImage imageNamed:@"Default.png"]` nil or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using an asset catalog.  This seemed to work.

```
UIColor *image = [[UIColor alloc] initWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"LaunchImage"]];
self.view.backgroundColor = image;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since Xcode was updated for iOS7, the image file @"Default.png" is no longer created with new projects.  So unless you name a file @"Default.png" and put it in the project, the UIImage you create won't have the desired image attached to it.

Also, the @"Default.png" image is usually just a black background.  You can achieve the same thing by simply setting the background color to black.

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

Answer (score 0):

I tried your above code and seems to be perfect.i tried this on my device and its work perfectly while i also faced the issue of white background with simulator.I will suggest:-

1)reset the simulator and quit it.

2)re-run your project.

your issue will get solved.It works perfect..

Hope this will help you out.